# This might be the most un-self aware book cover of all time

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does "un-self" mean "objective/realistic"?  Is the phrase "This might be the most un-self aware book cover of all time" a bit sarcastic?

> Sam Harris liked
> Shadi Hamid tweeted:

**This might be the most un-self aware book cover of all time**.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be understood as un-(self-aware). The cover is the opposite of self-aware.

The implication seems to be that Shadi Hamid is saying that this book and its author are unaware that they are themselves racist.  I make no comment on whether Shadi Hamid is correct.

Comment: Yes, the adjective should be un-self-aware.

Comment: And to answer the second part of the OP's question: No, it isn't a "bit" sarcastic.  It is a heck of a _lot_ sarcastic.

Comment: Actually I don't think it is "sarcastic",  at least not in the way the OP implies.  The OP asks "does un-self" mean objective,  so they think that tweet means "This is the most objective and aware cover of all time".  With the ironic meaning that it isn't objective nor aware. In fact I think the tweeter is being quite direct, and so not "ironic" or "sarcastic".